# loadrunner11 The Chinese log of server in Replay Log show the mess

Tags: testing, loadrunner

I use Loadrunner to write a HTTP request script in the Java Vuser.Then I use `web.reg_save_param()` to receive the response.But the response log in Replay Log show the mess.I have no idea to resolve it.The logs are following:

```
`Notify: Saving Parameter "resp = HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nServer: Apache- 
Coyote/x.xx\r\nContent-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8\r\nTransfer-Encoding: 
chunked\r\nVary: Accept-Encoding\r\nDate: Mon, 23 Jul 2018 07:50:03 
GMT\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n{"charset":"utf- 
8","Id":"xxxxxx","Type":"0","respCode":"xxxxx",
"respDesc":"鏌ヨ璁㈠崟鎴愬姛","FinishTime":"2018xxxxx",
"RespCode":"OK","RespDesc":"浜ゆ槗鎴愬 
姛","State":"02"}".`
```

Comment: LR 11 doesn't support unicode well so it will use the locale settings of your machine to interpret the response. You will need to set the locale setting to the language expected from the website.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it with the code `String r = new String(m.getBytes("GBK"),"UTF-8");` after the response logs saved.Then I can print the correct logs.